# Accidentally formatted directly Drive C:. Unable to detect partition while formatting

Tags: windows, boot, bootloader, partition-recovery

I accidentally formatted both Drive C: (which operating system is installed) as well as Drive D: (total of 2 partitions)

I an now trying to format my machine and now, unable to detect my internal hard disk drive.

Please help.

Comment: If you formatted both, what are you using now?

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to format hard disk of your machine? Did you try using any disk utilities?

try booting your machine from one of the linux distro live CD (For example Ubuntu) and try to format your hard drive using GParted. Read more about formatting using Gparted below link.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ReformattingPartition

You can also try the writing GParted Live image into a USB or CD and boot into it to format your drives.
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I formatted it directly (like when you format a flash drive). When trying to format it, we are unable to see any free space to make a partition with.

Comment: And yes, we are using disk formatting the machine. We already tried the repair your computer feature of the disk however, still no luck. hope you can help me out

Comment: I used to ran into problems with my partitions. I simply used to boot into ubuntu live cd, fire up Gparted and delte/create NTFS partition and format partitions. Did you try the disk management tool comes with Windows installer?

Comment: Thank you for your respond. It seems that the whole drive is on read-only as it was the error we currently receiving. I shall try to boot ubuntu live cd as what you instructed. Many thanks.